# How To Invoke Anonymous Function on Map Load

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a JS code like this which I have assigned an anonymous function to `photos` variable in `map.on("load", function() {}` now it seems the `photos` is never invoking! as even I tried to do a simple `console.log("Is This working")` it is not loading the log!

I am using the second function instead of ESRI's builtin `esriRequest();` since the native function is already taking `URL` to read JSON file from server but I am making points dynamically on fly. so I tough I must use mu own function here.

```
 var photos;
 map.on("load", function() {
          domStyle.set(query("a.action.zoomTo")[0], "display", "none");
          photos = function(){
            for (var i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
            var point = new Point(projects[i].Longitude, projects[i].Latitude);
            var pointSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(); 
            pointSymbol.setStyle(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE);
            pointSymbol.setSize(9);
            var pointInfoTemplate = new InfoTemplate(); 
            pointInfoTemplate.setTitle("Project Details");
            pointInfoTemplate.setContent('   ');
            var pointGraphic = new Graphic(point, pointSymbol).setInfoTemplate(pointInfoTemplate);
            points.push(pointGraphic);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
            map.graphics.add(points[i]);
        }
        console.log(points);
        };
            photos.then(addClusters, error);
        });
```

Can you please let me know why this is not working?

Comment: Which version of the JS API are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your line:

```
photos.then(addClusters, error);
```

... is not calling the photos function. You would have to add parenthesis like this:

```
photos().then(addClusters, error);
```

Note that you can only call `.then(...)` on a function that returns a deferred, so you may have problems having this code call `addClusters` too.